# Make Apple Hardware Test work on Mid 2009 MBP with OS X Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, gpu, apple-hardware-test

I had some graphics issues after running Bluestacks to run WhatsApp. The screen flickered until I shut down the app and I got worried. So wanted to verify my system using AHT.

I got a AHT .pkg package from an [Apple forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/18589412#18589412) to make Apple Hardware Test work on my mid-2009 MBP (no more AppleCare available) running OS X Mavericks. It used to run Snow Leopard - Apple staff upgraded to SL before giving me the MBP).

Apple [mentioned](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) that Snow Leopard normally ran AHT from the second CD, but I do not have that nor do I have a backup. I tried all options like command-D and D and even alt-D (they talk about these [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46344/why-is-apple-hardware-test-aht-not-loading-when-pressing-key-d-on-system-start?rq=1) as well), but none worked so I decided to go this path.

Now when I restart and press D I see a brief flicker and then my Macbook Pro turns off. Fortunately it still runs, but I want this to work of course. Why is this happening? Are these kinds of errors logged somewhere?

There are tools to access the EFI Bootloader and perform diagnostics, add partitions and so on using rEFIt as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777437/efi-console-on-mac-os-x-intel) on SO. I might give that a shot to see how it all works.

Answer (score 1):

it is d you have to hold down to run the Harware Test from the Second DVD that cames with your Mac when you Buy it. I don't know how it is on the Macs that don't have a Disc-Slot. Maybe Apple has added the Hardware Test to the Recovery Partition.

Keep in Mind what do you do if the Check brings up a Failure? - And all the Time you maybe need to figure out what exactly is the Failure from a cryptic Error code!! - I highly recommend you ro bring your Mac to a local apple retail store so they can check it for you it will cost something but still less then the time you will be spending to do it yourself.