# MacBook Pro can't run hardware test with pressing "D" key on reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-hardware-test

I have a 13" Late 2012 MacBook Pro which works fine. I am trying to run Hardware test following the instructions in the Apple Support document, [How to use Apple Hardware Test on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201257), but it is not working.

If I hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key while booting, it does not do anything. However, If I hold <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and then chose Wi-Fi connection in recovery mode, it shows the following error:

```
Error: 0x8000000000000003. Cannot Load 'EFI/Drivers/TestSupport.efi' 
Status: 0x00000003
```

There is installed macOS Mojave 10.14.4 over USB today.

**Update**: The question:

- [Why is Apple hardware test (AHT) not loading when pressing key D on system start?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46344/why-is-apple-hardware-test-aht-not-loading-when-pressing-key-d-on-system-start)

doesn't describe my situation, because in the mentioned case, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works, and no error message is thrown.

Comment: i didnt find out more information from other questions, they are old or not helped me

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! It's not really clear what exactly your question is here, can you please clarify? Also: why do you need to run the hardware test in the first place?

Comment: @nohillside im going to sell it. Buyer came and started testing, and its not started.

Comment: Please have a look at the linked question and the answers there. If they don‘t work for you, please *edit* your question to indicate what you have tried and how it didn‘t work.

Comment: a did. But linked question is not my situation, so it cant solve my problem.

Comment: even did like in this: https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest, but also didn't helped